# Can Protocol Buffer be used for uploading data from android device to server?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

recently I came across protocol buffer
and my understanding so far is that it is a substitute for XML/JSON.
So mostly in android applications we get the data in XML/JSON format and parse it and then display the contents in our app. but I never came across any scenario where a JSON or XML was created at application side and then uploaded to the server.

So our current requirement asks us to capture some data and upload it in Protocol buffer format.

I just wanted to know the use cases for Protocol buffer.
Is this requirement feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is entirely feasible; all you need is a protobuf library that targets your stack; based on the [library list](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), I would suggest you look at the official Google protobuf java implementation, or "square/wire" - assuming you are coding in java.